# JQuery - One function Negates another (slider not showing after .load(function())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im having som trouble with jquery funcion, 
after i add function to hide elements while page is still loading, the jquery slider i use wont show. (loading function works perfecly) It just negated the function of my slider:

Heres Jquery code of that calls slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            var unleash = $("#outer").unleash({double_dist: ["28%","28%","28%","28%","32%","28%"]}).data("plugin_unleash");

    });
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
```

and heres the element-hiding function:

```
<body>
  <div class="loading">
    <img src="indicator.gif"/>
  </div>

  <div class="content" style="display: none;">
    <!-- page content goes here --> 
  </div>
</body>


$(window).load(function(){
  $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
  $(".content").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

If someone could lookt at this and tell me what am i doing wrong i would be thankful:)

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Is the "slider" doing anything based on the location and size of the content? i don't see any in the code you've provided, but it's difficult to tell with it obfuscated in that way. Is that outputted by dreamweaver? Ah i completely missed .unleashed. the plugin likely requires the elements to be visible when initializing.

Comment: one issue might be the `$(window).load` occurs after `$(document).ready`.Try calling your plugin in callback of `$('.content).fadeIn`